# Annotating a Subquery with queryset filtering methods from another model through Many to Many fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm not sure how to make this possible, but I'm hoping to understand the intended method to do the following:

I have a simple model:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name = models.TextField()
    main_titles = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Book",
        through="BookMainAuthor",
        related_name="main_authors",
    )

    objects = AuthorManager.from_queryset(AuthorQuerySet)()


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    title = models.TextField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey("Genre", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    objects = BookManager.from_queryset(BookQuerySet)()


class BookQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def by_genre_scifi(self) -> QuerySet:
        return self.filter(**self.LOOKUP_POPULAR_SCIFI)
```

I'd like to add a new QuerySet method for `AuthorQuerySet` to annotate `Author` objects using the method from `BookQuerySet` above. I've tried the following, which is incorrect:

```py
class AuthorQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_total_titles_by_genres(self) -> QuerySet:
        main_titles_by_genre_sci_fi_query = Book.objects.filter(main_authors__in=[OuterRef('pk')]).all()
            .by_genre_sci_fi()
            .annotate(cnt=Count('*'))
            .values('cnt')[:1]

        return self.annotate(sci_fi_titles_total = 
             Subquery(main_titles_by_genre_sci_fi_query, output_field=IntegerField()))
```

Intended usage:

```py
annotated_authors = Author.objects.filter(<some filter>).annotate_with_total_titles_by_genres()
```

---

There are additional fields in the lookup not shown in the model above, but the method here is working, and returns a `BookQuerySet` filtered by the lookup:

```py
Book.objects.filter(main_authors__in=['some_author_id']).all().by_genre_sci_fi()
```

Similarly, I can run the subquery independently and get the count like so:

```py
`Book.objects.filter(main_authors__in=['some_author_id']).all()
            .by_genre_sci_fi()
            .annotate(cnt=Count('*'))
            .values('cnt')[:1]`
```

```
Out[1]: <BookQuerySet [{'cnt': 1}]>
```

However when I try to annotate using the AuthorQuerySet method above, I get `None` for every entry.

I wonder if there is an issue here with `OuterRef` and using `in` which will evaluate each character independently if it receives a string. If I try running it without the square parens:

`ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ""bookshop_author"" LINE 1: ...RE (U0."deleted_at" IS NULL AND U1."author_id" IN "bookshop_...`

Comment: Does it work if you run `main_titles_by_genre_sci_fi_query` as non-subquery (no OuterRef)

Comment: Yep, when I run it by placing the `pk` in square parens it works. I think the crux of the problem is using `OuterRef` with a list. I've edited the question to address your comment

Comment: @lys _why_ do you want to use the `in` lookup anyway? `OuterRef('pk')` is one value anyway, just write `main_authors=OuterRef('pk')`

Comment: Thanks, the reason is that `main_authors` is a list of Author objects returned from the m2m field. What I actually require is `OuterRef('pk')` in `main_authors`